# the image of $1$ by a homomorphism between unitary rings

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

let $R$ and $S$ be unitary rings and $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ a ring homomorphism.
is the following correct:

$\phi(1_R)=\phi(1_R\cdot1_R)=\phi(1_R)\cdot\phi(1_R)$ so $\phi(1_R)(1_S-\phi(1_R))=0_S$ and so $\phi(1_R)$ could be anything in $S$ when $S$ is a general ring, i mean we can not conclude what values $\phi(1_R)$ could take in $S$ . But when $S$ is an integral domain then we can say that we have $\phi(1_R)=0_S$ or $1_S-\phi(1_R)=0_S$ i.e, $\phi(1_R)=1_S$. Moreover when $\phi$ is a monomorphism then since only $0_R$ maps to $0_S$ then necessarily   $\phi(1_R)=1_S$.

Comment: Your second step is wrong. Note that you're substracting things that are in different rings.

Comment: i made the correction, thanks !

Comment: This is correct. For example, $\phi : \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto (x,0)$ is additive and multiplicative, but doesn't map $1$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: this is because $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ is not an integral domain since $(1,0).(0,1)=(0,0)$. but note that this is a monomorphism from the integral domain $\mathbb Z$ to the unitary ring $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$

Comment: I mean "we can not conclude what values $\phi(1_R)$ could take in S" is correct.

Comment: @palio: you don't need $\phi$ to be injective, it suffices that it be non-zero.

Comment: Your title is weird: usually "unitary ring homomorphis" means that the image of $1$ is $1$!

Comment: @Weltschmerz : yes absolutely since if $\phi(1_R)=0_S$ then $\forall r\in R$, we have $\phi(r)=\phi(1_R.r)=\phi(1_R).\phi(r)=0_S.\phi(r)=0_S$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : i just mean the rings are unitary so we can speak of $1_R$ and $1_S$ but my problem is to know $\phi(1_R)$ under different conditions. Moreover i'm not able to change the title so if you have access please do it .. thanks

Comment: Why can't you change the title? Right below the body of your question, there is a link which reads «edit» which allows you to edit the question *and* the title.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : i hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you correctly proved, it's true when $S$ is an integral domain.

Another fact is that if the homomorphism is surjective, then $\phi(1_R)$ is the identity in $S$, regardless of what $S$ is like. To prove it just check what it does to any other element of $S$.

Also true: if $R$ and $S$ are non-trivial rings, $S$ has an identity $1_S$, $\phi$ is injective and $1_S$ is in $\phi(R)$ then $R$ has an identity and $\phi(1_R)=1_S$.

Comment: the example that @Qil gave is surjective but $\phi(1)$ is not $(1,1)$

Comment: @palio: I don't think it's surjective.

Comment: i'm sorry it is clearly not surjective

Comment: i could'nt see why being surjective $\phi$ must map $1_R$ to $1_S$?

Comment: @palio: Pick any $y\in S$. Then $\phi(1_R)y=\phi(1_R)\phi(x)$ for some $x$ in $R$ because $\phi$ is surjective. Now, $\phi(1_R)\phi(x)=\phi(1_R x)=\phi(x)=y$. And you know that the identity in a ring is unique. Hence $\phi(1_R)=1_S$.

Comment: yes absolutely!!! since for any $y\in S$ we have that $\phi(1_R).y=y$ then $\phi(1_R)$ is an identity in $S$ and so necessarily $\phi(1_R)=1_S$

Answer (score 4):

Our OP palio's remarks are essentially correct.

My approach to this issue is very similar, to wit:

The conclusion that

$\phi(1_R) = 1_S \tag 0$

always holds true when $\phi$ is surjective; for let

$\phi:R \to S \tag 1$

be a homomorphism 'twixt the (*not necessarily commutative*) rings $R$ and $S$ such that

$\text{Range}(\phi) = S; \tag 2$

then for any

$s \in S \tag 3$

there is some

$r \in R \tag 4$

with

$\phi(r) = s; \tag 5$

since

$r1_R = 1_R r = r, \tag 6$

we have

$s = \phi(r) = \phi(r1_R) = \phi(r)(1_R) = s\phi(1_R), \tag 7$

and

$s = \phi(r) = \phi(1_Rr) = \phi(1_R)\phi(r) = \phi(1_R)s; \tag 8$

since (7)-(8) hold for any $s \in S$, we see by definiton that

$\phi(1_R) = 1_S, \tag 9$

that is, $\phi(1_R)$ is the multiplicative identity $1_S$ of $S$; note that we have in fact *proved* the existence of $1_S$ in this argument.

Of course, when $S$ has no zero divisors (i.e. is an *integral domain* in the event that it is commutative), then as was done by our OP palio we may write

$1_R = 1_R^2 \Longrightarrow \phi(1_R) = (\phi(1_R))^2 \Longrightarrow \phi(1_R) - (\phi(1_R))^2 = 0$
$\Longrightarrow \phi(1_R)(1_S - \phi(1_R)) = 0; \tag{9.1}$

we note that unless $\phi$ is the trivial homomorphism we have

$\phi(1_R) \ne 0 \tag{9.2}$

lest

$\forall r \in R, \; \phi(r) = \phi(r1_R)$
$= \phi(r) \phi(1_R) = \phi(r) \cdot 0 = 0, \tag{9.3}$

contradicting the non-triviality of $\phi$; this fact, combined with (9.1) implies

$1_S - \phi(1_R) = 0, \tag{9.4}$

that is

$\phi(1_R) = 1_S. \tag{9.5}$

If

$\text{Range}(\phi) \ne S, \tag{10}$

then $\phi(1_R)$ may not be the unit of $S$; a counterexample is provided by the homomorphism

$\phi:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \tag{11}$

defined by

$\phi(r) = (r, 0), \; \forall r \in \Bbb Z; \tag{12}$

then

$\phi(1) = (1, 0), \tag{13}$

but the multiplicative identity of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ is $(1, 1)$.

Here we of course assume the operations in $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ act *component-wise*, that is

$(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d), \tag{14}$

and

$(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac, bd). \tag{15}$