# Example of ring "quasi-homomorphism" not conserving multiplicative identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Example of ring "quasi-homomorphism" not conserving multiplicative identity?

I'm using a definition of homomorphism that requires f(1)=1 and I'm trying understand the reasons and consequence of this point.

I mean: if we're connecting two rings with identity, does this not force f(1)=1?

Comment: See: [In a ring homomorphism we always have $f(1) = 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/270883/49437) and [the image of 1 by a homomorphism between unitary rings](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78172/the-image-of-1-by-a-homomorphism-between-unitary-rings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any idempotent $e\notin\{0,1\}$ in any ring $R$.

The inclusion of $eRe\rightarrow R$ does not preserve identity.

---

To add some details, it is easy to check that $eRe$ is a subring of $R$ with identity $e$. The inclusion $x\mapsto x$ would not send $e$ to 1 in $R$, and so it does not preserve identity. There is no need for $e$ to be central.

Comment: You should ask for $e$ to be central, or else this need not be a map of rings.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer No, that's superfluous. It is an inclusion map of a subring into a ring... I don't see why centrality of $e$ matters to map $ere\mapsto ere$.

Comment: I'm guessing @David was thinking of the projection $R \to eRe : x \mapsto exe$.

Comment: My bad, you're right.

Comment: Which is the identity of $eRe$? I thing $1=ee=e1e$ since for all $a\in eRe$ there is $a'\in R$ such that $a=ea'e$, thus $1a=1ea'e=ea'e=a$. Then the identity *is* preserved by the inclusion. What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: With other words, how do you see that $e$ is the identity of $eRe$?

Comment: @AaronLenz It's true that $1a=a$ for all $a\in eRe$, but that does not mean $ee=1$.  You have to know $1\in eRe$, which isn't always the case.  If you just use a simple example like $F_2\times F_2$, $e=(1,0)$, you will see.

Comment: $e$ is the identity of $eRe$ by trivial computation: $e(ere)=(ere)e=ere$ for every $ere\in eRe$.  And of course $e=e1e\in eRe$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made the error to consider idempotent as $ee=1$ instead of what it is, $ee=e$.

Comment: @AaronLenz No problem: glad you got on track.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiplicative and additive maps between rings that do not preserve identity. For instance $i: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ given by $i(n)=(0,n)$. One might call such a map a rng homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

consider $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $f(a)=2\cdot a$.

Comment: This is not a multiplicative map, because $4=f(1)f(1)\neq f(1)$.

Comment: I apologize (going to sleep now).